# Build error for SDL2-2.0.5 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04, sdl-2

```
uranus@uranus:~/lib/SDL2-2.0.5$ make
/bin/bash build-scripts/updaterev.sh
    LTLINK build/libSDL2.la
build/.libs/SDL_mirvideo.o: In function 'MIR_InitDisplayFromOutput':
/home/uranus/lib/SDL2-2.0.5/src/video/mir/SDL_mirvideo.c:258: undefined reference to 'mir_output_get_current_mode'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:147: recipe for target 'build/libSDL2.la' failed
make: *** [build/libSDL2.la] Error 1
```

SDL2 Configure Summary:

```
Building Shared Libraries
Building Static Libraries
Enabled modules : atomic audio video render events joystick haptic power filesystem threads timers file loadso cpuinfo assembly
Assembly Math   : mmx 3dnow sse sse2
Audio drivers   : disk dummy oss alsa(dynamic) pulse(dynamic) sndio
Video drivers   : dummy x11(dynamic) opengl opengl_es2 mir(dynamic)
X11 libraries   : xcursor xdbe xinerama xinput2 xinput2_multitouch xrandr xscrnsaver xshape xvidmode
Input drivers   : linuxev linuxkd
Using libudev   : YES
Using dbus      : YES
Using ime       : YES
Using ibus      : NO
Using fcitx     : NO
```

Answer (score 1):

The linker needs the name of the library where is this function.

I fixed it, adding in my Makefile file "-lmirclient".

```
# diff  Makefile Makefile-ORG
26c26
< EXTRA_LDFLAGS =  -Wl,--no-undefined -lm -ldl  -lasound -lm -ldl -lpthread -lsndio  -lX11 -lXext -lXcursor -lXinerama -lXi -lXrandr -lXss -lXxf86vm -lpthread -lrt -lmirclient
---
> EXTRA_LDFLAGS =  -Wl,--no-undefined -lm -ldl  -lasound -lm -ldl -lpthread -lsndio  -lX11 -lXext -lXcursor -lXinerama -lXi -lXrandr -lXss -lXxf86vm -lpthread -lrt 
#
```

Comment: How did you know this? Is there a tool to find this out?

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix is to set static linking to the mir library when running configure:

```
./configure --enable-mir-shared=no
```

This causes the `EXTRA_LDFLAGS` variable to have the `-lmirclient` option added to it, as per Juan's answer.

As for why there is a problem, see [bug 3539](https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3539), which was resolved in a [patch](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/rev/3034ea08d805) shortly after.

Looking at the patch, it appears there was a missing definition needed to allow dynamic linking to the 'mir_output_get_current_mode' function mentioned in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and i couldn't solve 
but i used SDL2.0.3 and i didn't face any problems and it worked and Compiled fine with me
You can install it from here
https://sourceforge.net/projects/libsdl/files/SDL/2.0.3/